# What are the supported Date and Time Formats in Spacy 2.0

Tags: spacy

I am using the following models in my application:

en_core_web_sm

xx_ent_wiki_sm

I wanted to know the supported Date and Time formats that default Spacy model can extract.

Python Version Used:3.6
spaCy Version Used: 2.0.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English models were trained on the OntoNotes 5 corpus, which supports the [more extensive label scheme](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities) including `DATE` and `TIME`.

The `xx_ent_wiki_sm` model was trained on a Wikipedia corpus with a [more limited](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#ner-wikipedia-scheme) label scheme and only recognises `PER`, `LOC`, `ORG` and `MISC` out of the box ([model details here](https://spacy.io/models/xx#xx_ent_wiki_sm)).

When using the models to extract mentions of date and time, it's important to keep in mind that it's a statistical process – so the results you see will depend on the context and the data the models were trained on. Depending on the texts you're working with, you likely want to [update and fine-tune](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner) the pre-trained models with more examples specific to your application, or try a rule-based approach instead. Also see [this thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/513#issuecomment-377273861) for more details on date and time parsing.

Comment: Would like to let the model [release](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases) reference, which is very simple to find different models and its steps to install it. Using the site is kinda a mess.